# Pandas: Getting back original numpy array stored in DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

Consider the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
k = pd.DataFrame({"a": list(a)})
```

[image: df]

I'd like to retrieve the original numpy array. However, when I call `.values` I get something different.

[image: values]

How can I get the original numpy array, that looks like this:

```
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6],
       [7, 8]])
```

?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create nested lists and convert to 2d array:

```
np.array(k['a'].tolist())
```